# Struggling to authorize a web app integration via Postman

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, webservices, oauth2

I have created a web app component in Salesforce Marketing Cloud, and now I'm trying to get the OAuth2.0 flow to work in Postman.

First, I use the Authorization tab in Postman to request a token.
[image]

Then I'm taken out to my browser, where I log in to Salesforce. My browser redirects to the Callback URL for postman and tells me my call is authenticated. When I go back to Postman, it presents me with information about the token I've just received.

Now here's my first point of confusion. If I compare the Access Token that's been received by Postman to the "code" parameter returned in the callback URL, they are not the same.

Last few characters of the code appended to the callback URL:
[image: Last few characters of the code appended to the callback URL]
Last few characters of the Access Token retrieved by Postman:
[image: Last few characters of the Access Token retrieved by Postman]

Why are these values different? Where is Postman even getting this different access key information if not from the code appended to the callback URL?

Once I get the authorization code, I try to make a call to the v2/token endpoint to obtain an access key, following [this documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/access-token-app.htm). In the next screenshot, I use the value appended to the callback URL as the "code" parameter in my request, but I've also tried using the access code that was retrieved by Postman. Both result in an "invalid authorization code" error.

[image]

This is my first time ever using an OAuth2.0 workflow, so I'm not sure, but it occurs to me that the reason the codes are different and my token request is failing is that Postman has already made the token request using the authorization code provided to the callback URL. In that case, the authorization code has already been exchanged for an access key, so it's no longer valid.

Assuming that's the case, I've tried using the Access Key in the `<fuelauth>` header of a SOAP request. (it's also used as a Bearer token in the authorization header). But that gives me an error saying that "API permission failed". For my testing purposes, I've checked every box in the scope of the app setup, including offline access. Does that mean that my user credentials don't have permission to call an API? Or does it mean something else about my request is failing?

[image]

Comment: There is an unofficial Salesforce collection that includes MC for Postman. I can't tell from your screenshots if you have it already, maybe it will help? Blog post with link about it here https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/03/explore-the-salesforce-apis-with-a-postman-collection.html

Comment: What is application that will be making the API request? Specifically will the integration request end user context? If not a server to server integration type with client credentials will make the workflow much easier (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/integration-s2s-client-credentials.htm).

Comment: Also, Rick linked to the Postman collection for Salesforce platform which is great however the Marketing Cloud collection is available here (https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/postman). We've built the collection in such a way that you can provide a few variables and auth is handled automatically as a pre-request script at the collection level.

Comment: Thanks, @AaronCates, I'll take a look at that collection. I'll be calling the API from a browser, so unfortunately I need the added security of a web app.

Comment: It's possible to call the API from a web app and still use client credentials flow. It comes down to if you can secure the client credentials securely server side. So in a node.js app I would securely store the credentials server side, have client side post a request to a processing route server side that makes the call to Marketing Cloud. Just depends on your overall app design.

Comment: In this case, I eventually want to call this API from a Google Apps script. The end goal is to pull data from Salesforce into a Google Sheet so I don't have to type numbers into cells every day.

Answer (score 2):

After forking the [collection](https://github.com/salesforce-marketingcloud/postman/blob/master/install-the-collection.md#configure-the-collection) posted by Aaron Cates, I was able to get the authentication to work! I was correct in my theory that the OAuth2.0 flow was making the token request for me, so I didn't need to make a call to the v2/token endpoint.

After securing the access key and trying the v1/validateEmail request recommended in the collection's setup instructions, I kept getting the response:

```
"message": "Insufficient privileges to complete this action.",
"errorcode": 20002,
"documentation": ""
```

The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/error-handling.htm) for that error made me think that my user credentials didn't allow me to make API calls, ([this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/66295/user-not-authorized-error) has a helpful comment showing exactly what permission the role needs to have) so I went through my roles and permissions in my sandbox environment and enabled everything, logged out, and then back in. I was still getting the same error.

More googling led me to [this question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/313457/rest-api-to-add-data-into-a-data-extension-leads-to-error-20002), where a comment by our almighty lord and savior Gortonington mentioned that this error will show up if the scope passed in the authentication call doesn't match the scope of the API component. Since the [scope parameter](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-app-development.meta/mc-app-development/access-token-s2s.htm) isn't actually required, I thought that leaving it blank would make it default to all of the scopes enabled in the component setup.

But I realized that Postman isn't actually omitting the scope parameter when I leave it blank in the Authorization tab. It was passing the parameter but leaving the values blank, which Marketing Cloud interprets as "no scopes are allowed", not "all scopes are allowed". So I googled what scopes are needed for each endpoint, which are all listed [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/rest-permissions-and-scopes.htm). Providing the value "email_read" in the scopes section of the Authorization tab *finally* gave me a 200 OK response.

Postman is just my testing environment, but I think I can assume that any OAuth2.0 library I use will retrieve the access key for me in the same way. Hopefully this whole journey helps someone else who's getting lost in the weeds of OAuth2.0 flows.